# Can't Create New AVD

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-virtual-device

I copy my android-sdk-linux folder from office desktop to my laptop, with setting appropriate path but cannot create any avd. Only show this error message in console, when click new avd.

```
[2012-05-29 22:09:54 - SDK Manager] Failed to create the SD card.
[2012-05-29 22:09:55 - SDK Manager] Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder.
```

anyone please give me some tricks

Edit: BTW, in my pc , i dont have home/username/.android/avd. SO what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

just delete the android folder which is saved in (documents and settings\username) in that delete the .android folder restart ur pc and open eclipse and recreate a new avd it works fine..

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar issues when setting up a new Android SDK. The error message that you mentioned occours usually due to the access permissions to the files in the "tools" folder in the Android SDK directory.

Use

```
cd [Path to Android SDK]/Tools/ 
chmod 755 *
```

Also for the `/home/[USER_NAME]/.android/avd folder`, give `777` permision using

```
chmod 777 /home/[USER_NAME]/.android/avd command
```